# How to add permalinks to tree nodes in Markdown nav file (mkdocs.yml)?

Tags: markdown, mkdocs

The mkdocs.yml nav file I am working with includes a hierarchical tree of a manuals website with several categories and subcategories the content articles fall into; the tree is absolutely virtual and not based on a folder structure/website path. I am looking for a way to generate permalinks for each of the tree's nodes (categories).
If that is impossible with Markdown or its extensions than perhaps html/css elements could be used.

I am very new to Markdown and mkdocs; I googled thoroughly to get a solution but failed to find one.

```
site_name: My Site
site_dir: docs/guides/
site_url: http://example.net/
docs_dir: 'src'
nav:
  - 'TOP LEVEL CATEGORY':
    - 'BOTTOM LEVEL CATEGORY':
         - Manual 1: 'manuals/Manual1.md'
         - Manual 2: 'manuals/Manual2.md'
    - 'BOTTOM LEVEL 2':
{...}
  - 'TOP LEVEL CATEGORY 2':
{...}

markdown_extensions:
    - smarty
    - toc:
        permalink: True
        separator: "_"
    - sane_lists
    - tables
    - meta
    - fenced_code
    - admonition
    - footnotes
```

The virtual hierarchical tree with expandable nodes which is built is all right, but I really need to generate permalinks for each category and subcategory, e.g.
*example.net/docs/guides/toplevelcat/bottomlevelcat*
or
*example.net/docs/guides/toplevelcat#bottomlevelcat*
it does not matter how exactly the links will be organized and whether they are generated automatically or preset manually

the link could lead to an index page with all manuals belonging to the category OR just display the root *mysite.net/docs/guides/* page with the required category expanded

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported by MkDocs at this time, but may be possible with a [custom theme](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/custom-themes/).

In [#1042](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/pull/1042), you can find an attempt at a solution which was ultimately rejected for a number of reasons. That said, you should be able to simulate something similar with a custom theme.

MkDocs does not care if the structure of the `nav` matches any actual file structure. So you can arrangement the nesting structure however you want. Just make sure the first child of any "section" points at an index file. Perhaps something like this:

```
nav:
  - 'TOP LEVEL CATEGORY':
    - 'toplevel1/index.md'
    - 'BOTTOM LEVEL CATEGORY':
         - 'bottomlevel1/index.md'
         - Manual 1: 'manuals/Manual1.md'
         - Manual 2: 'manuals/Manual2.md'
    - 'BOTTOM LEVEL 2':
         - 'bottomlevel2/index.md'
```

Note that each section includes a unique index file. Of course index files must be named `index.md` so the only way to make them unique is for each one to be in a unique subdirectory. Also notice that there is no title assigned to the index pages. Presumably, the section title will be used.

Then in your theme template you need to check for children and if the first child is an index, use that as the link for that section. Then when looping through the children, be sure to skip the index in the nested level.

Perhaps something like this:

```
{% if nav|length>1 %}
    <ul>
    {% for nav_item in nav %}
        {% if nav_item.children %}
            <li>{% if nav_item.children[0].is_index %}
                    <a href="{{ nav_item.children[0].url|url }}">{{ nav_item.title }}</a>
                {% else %}
                    {{ nav_item.title }}
                {% endif %}
                <ul>
                {% for nav_item in nav_item.children[1:] %}
                    <li class="{% if nav_item.active%}current{% endif %}">
                        <a href="{{ nav_item.url|url }}">{{ nav_item.title }}</a>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="{% if nav_item.active%}current{% endif %}">
                <a href="{{ nav_item.url|url }}">{{ nav_item.title }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

By way of explanation, the above is simply a slightly modified version of the [example](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/custom-themes/#nav-example) in the docs. Where the section title was displayed in the original (`{{ nav_item.title }}`), we instead check if the first child is an index file and, if so, display a link to the index page instead. Of course, we include a fallback for those occasions where there is no index.

```
{% if nav_item.children[0].is_index %}
    <a href="{{ nav_item.children[0].url|url }}">{{ nav_item.title }}</a>
{% else %}
    {{ nav_item.title }}
{% endif %}
```

Then when stepping through the children, we want to avoid including the index file. I used `{% for nav_item in nav_item.children[1:] %}` in my example (`[1:]` slices the list to exclude the first item), but that assumes there always is an index file. Some other solutions may be better and left as a exercise for the reader. The [Jinja documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) may be helpful here.

Also note that the above template only accounts for one level of nesting. A more sophisticated solution would need to be developed to handle multiple nesting levels. For example, you might want to define a Jinja macro, which each level calls recursively.

Also of note is that you don't need to develop a complete custom theme. You might want to instead [override a template block](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/styling-your-docs/#overriding-template-blocks) of an existing theme which your own custom navigation.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented a plugin for this functionality, "**[mkdocs-section-index](https://github.com/oprypin/mkdocs-section-index)**", and it works similarly to [what @Waylan describes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54598748) -- or actually more similar to [the dropped pull request #1042](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/pull/1042), because most of the logic is *outside* of the theme/template. The special sections with a link are explicitly put into the nav and presented as such to the theme, so it doesn't need to find and exclude this "first child" itself.

*mkdocs.yml*:

```yaml
plugins:
  - section-index
nav:
  - Frob: index.md
  - Baz: baz.md
  - Borgs:
    - borgs/index.md
    - Bar: borgs/bar.md
    - Foo: borgs/foo.md
```

That gives you a nav like this:

> - [Frob](https://example.org/index.html)
> - [Baz](https://example.org/baz.html)
> - [Borgs](https://example.org/borgs/index.html)
>
>   - [Bar](https://example.org/borgs/bar.html)
>   - [Foo](https://example.org/borgs/foo.html)

It makes sense to me that this functionality couldn't be included by default, but a plugin as a way to opt in seems perfectly fine.